help identifying this scream/yell sfx
This is such a shot in the dark, I found it somewhere, I don't remember where tho and it had some music over it which I was able to split using some AI website. I want to find the clean version of it.
audio

Hard to tell which fx without the dry version. Maybe there is just a lot of spit in the mouth so it just sounds like this. Maybe there is some amplitude modulation, maybe a soft chorus
